# Do I need to use comparative degree?

Tags: grammar, comparatives

> Maybe it's a little long story.
>   Maybe it's a little longer story.

Comment: It depends on the context. Each sentence has a different meaning that would be used in different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, the placement of "story" at the end of the sentence is very strange.  Either "it's" should be referring to the story as mentioned in a previous sentence, or you should say "Maybe the story is a little long/longer".

Secondly:
"Maybe the story is a little long" means that you could, if you tried, shorten the story up and still cover everything you need.  (Perhaps someone said "You rambled a heck of a lot in that story.")

"Maybe the story is a little longer" means that you arrived at the apparent end of the story but you're letting the listeners know that there's actually still something to be told.  (Perhaps someone said "What, that was the end??  Awwww, I wanted something more to happen.")

Comment: I get it. It looks like what you say. But I still don't know why. 'Maybe the story is a little longer than what it looks like' ?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  It's a little longer than what you've told so far, there's a little more to tell.

Answer (score 2):

> *Maybe it’s **a little long** story* (wrong)
>
> *Maybe it’s **a little longer** story* (wrong)

Those are definitely ungrammatical. *A little long* and *a little longer* are both fine adjective phrases, but they can’t be used before a noun like that, I guess because of the determiner *a* in them. Similarly you can’t say:

> *It was a **the whole night long** party.* (wrong)
>
> *It was **a whole night long** party.* (still wrong)

Anything that appears before a noun like that has to be quite simple in structure.

> *The pond was **only two feet deep**.* (ok)
>
> *It was an **only two feet deep** pond.* (wrong)
>
> *The story is **familiar to all Russians**.* (ok)
>
> *It is a **familiar to all Russians** story.* (wrong)

However, an adjective modified by an adverb is fine:

> *Maybe it’s an **overly long** story.* (ok)
>
> *Maybe it’s a **slightly longer** story.* (ok)
>
> *Maybe this is a **totally unnecessary** extra example.* (ok)

Hellion is right about the difference between *long* and *longer* here and the other possible solution:

> *Maybe the story is a little long.* (ok)
>
> *Maybe the story is a little longer.* (ok)

As a matter of style, I would say “Maybe that isn’t quite the end of the story.”

Comment: "maybe it's a little longer story" is not incorrect as a clause, as in "I know that one was short, but I have another; maybe it's a little longer story."

Comment: @oosterwal That definitely still sounds ungrammatical to me. I honestly can't even tell what it's supposed to mean. Do you mean that *a little longer story* is the same as *a longer little story*?

Comment: @Jason Orendorff: Consider these variations: A story, a little story, a long story, a longer story, a much longer story, and a little longer story.  In terms of 'story' the opposite of 'long' should be 'short', and the opposite of 'little' should be 'big'.  In the case of 'little longer story', 'longer' modifies 'story' and 'little' modifies 'longer'; 'little' is synonymous with 'bit' ('bit' meaning 'small amount', not 'binary digit'.)

Comment: @oosterwal OK, I see what you're saying now. I agree that *a little longer* and *a bit longer* are equally acceptable, and synonymous, and the same in grammatical structure. But I find *that story is bit longer* (with *bit* modifying *longer*) and *a bit longer story* both to be ungrammatical too. You don't?

Comment: I just realized you and I analyze *a bit longer* differently. I see *a bit* as an NP modifying *longer*: *[[a bit] longer]*. The same goes for *[[two feet] deep]*. Both *bit* and *feet* are nouns, and so is *little* in *a little longer*.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff:  I agree that 'that story is bit longer', and 'a bit longer story' are ungrammatical.  However, when used in a clause, 'that story is *little* longer' can be grammatical, as in, "We have examined both and find that story is little longer."  It's a bit formal or archaic; I would expect to read a sentence like that in Victorian literature.

Comment: Back to the original question:  To me, "Maybe ***it*** is a little longer story" comes across as an observation that begs the question "A little longer *than* ***what***?"

Comment: @Jason I still didn't get it. 'Maybe it’s an overly long story' 'Maybe it’s a little long story' looks like the same. can we just say 'Maybe it's a story' ?

Comment: @lovespring Yes, *Maybe it's a story* is fine. And yes, they do look the same, but the word *little* is special. There are a few places where you could use *little* as an adverb of degree just like *overly* --but this isn't one of them. You don't say *The story is little long*; you would say *The story is **a** little long.* See how weird it is? *a little* together makes an adverb. But you can't use that weird compound adverb before a noun the way you would with *overly/truly/amazingly/barely/somewhat/slightly*, because the word *a* wrecks the sense of the sentence.

Comment: The simple answer is "no you can't do that". And the grammatical reason why is: "*a little* is really odd and special; it's not quite like *overly*".